# Android MediaCodec: mpeg4 decoding

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am trying to decode video using AMediaCodec without AMediaExtractor. I have successfully decoded avc and hevc streams using it by passing NAL units and required codec specific info. in start.

However, I am having problem with mpeg4. Some files play perfectly but some files give this error:

> 07-13 04:19:20.962 10721-11341/? A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   GetObjectClass called with pending exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sample rate 524288160
>   07-13 04:19:20.962 10721-11341/? A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.media.AudioFormat$Builder
>   android.media.AudioFormat$Builder.setSampleRate(int)
>   (AudioFormat.java:891) 07-13 04:19:20.962 10721-11341/? A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void
>   android.media.AudioTrack.(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
>   (AudioTrack.java:416) 07-13 04:19:20.962 10721-11341/? A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void
>   android.media.AudioTrack.(int, int, int, int, int, int)
>   (AudioTrack.java:370)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What code are you using the play these files?

Comment: "Invalid sample rate 524288160" <-- this is your problem. but we can't solve this unless you publish the code.